# Make part of an UICollectionViewCell not clickable

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uicollectionviewcell

Basically what i want to do is to have a cell in a UICollectionView, which part of it will respond to tap, and part of it won't. 
This cell will be a normal cell that is expanded when tapped, showing a subview on the expanded area that doesn't respond to tap.

I considered expanding the cell and adding a subview **above it**, that wouldn't be clickable. But i think that is kind of a "bad" way of accomplishing it.

Is there a best way of doing this?

This is what i want to do:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need subclass `UICollectionViewCell`, then override `hitTest:withEvent` rather than `pointInside:withEvent`, inside `hitTest:withEvent:` you should define the `targetRect`, then check if the point user clicked is inside of `targetRect`.

Here is the code which works on my `tableViewCell` (similar for `collectionViewCell`).

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), 20);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(targetRect, point)) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your solution really seems interesting and plausible. However, i posted this question a while ago, and i have worked this out by using a UICollectionViewCell and a UIView. So, i expand the the cell to the desirable size, and place a view on top of the new expanded area. As i am not currently working on that project, i can't validate your answer right now. But, as soon as i can try your solution, i will give you a feedback. Thanks for the help anyway! =)

Comment: Good to hear you have fixed it. Putting a cover over expanded area is one good optional.

Answer (score 0):

With in the selector

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

you must return a cell, and in this function you should determine whether or not the cell is clickable and then simply do

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = shouldAllowTouch;
```

Comment: But this will make all the cell not clickable, and i want the top part to remain clickable, as explained in the picture.

Comment: you could make the non clickable cell section views

Comment: or, make the content that you don't want to be selectable in it's own cell and make that cell's user interaction not enabled

Comment: it's impossible to make part of a cell selectable unless you subclass the UICollectionViewCell, implement pointInside method and return NO if the touch is in the non selectable area, but then again idk if it still calls did select cell at index path